# sending data from activity to a dialog box

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating an app that has a `recyclerview` in the MainActivty.
What I am trying to achieve is when an item from the `recyclerview` is clicked it should pop in a dialog box with elaborated contents.

Is it possible to send data from an `activity` to `DialogFragment`?

any sugesstions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example from Google documentation

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    int mNum;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of MyDialogFragment, providing "num"
     * as an argument.
     */
    static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num) {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");

        // Pick a style based on the num.
        int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
        switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
            case 1: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
            case 2: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
            case 3: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_INPUT; break;
            case 4: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
            case 5: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
            case 6: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
            case 7: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
            case 8: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
        }
        switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
            case 4: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo; break;
            case 5: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog; break;
            case 6: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light; break;
            case 7: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Panel; break;
            case 8: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light; break;
        }
        setStyle(style, theme);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ((TextView)tv).setText("Dialog #" + mNum + ": using style "
                + getNameForNum(mNum));

        // Watch for button clicks.
        Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.show);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // When button is clicked, call up to owning activity.
                ((FragmentDialog)getActivity()).showDialog();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}

An example showDialog() method on the Activity could be:

void showDialog() {
    mStackLevel++;

    // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
    // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
    // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

Comment: thanx @ivan but this isnt what i was looking for

Comment: newInstance method creates DialogFragment and passes an argument in it. Then you may use this argument in your class. Could you explain what are you looking for in detail?

Comment: Whilst the example may be a little verbose, it does illustrate exactly what you asked for in your question.